# JSON Parsing in Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, parsing, factory

I am trying to get a list of ID from a JSON file.

So far, the only way to access the "id" object is by using this:

```
console.log(photos.photosets.photoset[0].id);
```

As you might tell, it only gives me the correct ID of the first item.

If I try this, it gives me an "undefined":

```
console.log(photos.photosets.photoset.id);
```

Comment: there is no question here. and it is also unclear how this relates to angular.

Answer (score 1):

No Angular, just JavaScript.

```
for (i = 0; i < photos.photosets.length; i++) {
 console.log(photos.photosets.photoset[i].id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate array of `photoset`'s and produce new array of ids from it. [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is convenient in this case:

```
var ids = photos.photosets.photoset.map(function(obj) {
    return obj.id;
});
```

Comment: ...so that way, I can use it from my factory into a controller?  That's what I'm aiming for, to replace ID's in a url by those from the Json...